# Set a column equal to a value in Oracle SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to Select a column and set it equal to 0. In SQL I just do this: SELECT Dealer_Fee = 0.

Do I have to use an update? When I try the same thing in Oracle I get "FROM keyword not found where expected."

Comment: do you want to permanently `UPDATE` it to that value?

Comment: SELECT is what you do when you want to query the data; UPDATE is when you want to change it. Which do you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what do you want to do and in which SQL dialect the construction you mentioned works. If you just want to retrieve some value and place it in a named column in Oracle you have to use [DUAL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries009.htm#sthref2275) table. Try this:

```
SELECT 0 AS dealer_fee FROM dual;
```

On the other hand, if you ment T-SQL and placing a value into variable you need to use PL/SQL [SELECT INTO](http://dba-oracle.com/t_pl_sql_plsql_select_into_clause.htm) clause, like that:

```
SELECT 0 INTO dealer_fee from dual;
```

If not try to explain in more detail what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

1) In Oracle you must specify FROM clause within SELECT, is not like MS sqlserver where you can omit a FROM clause.

2) If you want to update one specific value, you must use UPDATE clause instead SELECT.

hth

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Update` statement.  Please visit this oracle reference which explains the Update statement in detail: [Update Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/update_statement.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the reference for `UPDATE` in Oracle](http://psoug.org/reference/update.html):

```
UPDATE <table_name>
SET <column_name> = <value>
```